# Extract specified columns from a CSV file using Linux commands?

Tags: linux, csv

Is there a way to extract certain columns from a CSV file using Linux commands?  The CSV fields are quoted and *can* have commas inside a single column.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't migrate this as is as you have no sample data, and this is off topic as you haven't shown any evidence of doing this with a shell script. If you can edit this to demonstrate either, please flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: I disagree with this close - it is a valid succinct question and the second sentence merely points out that splitting on commas is not going to work.  Many of the other CSV-tagged questions are quite similar to this. **An answer**: I respectfully submit that the best way to process CSV files is with a tool designed to process CSV files, and one such tool is [csvfix](http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: csvfix solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the colums are separated in the form: "," and no " are inside the colums:

```
awk -F"\",\"" '{ print $3 }' data.csv  | tr -d "\""
```

The example prints colum three from data.csv. The tr command deletes the " when choosing the first or the last colum.